# Can somebody invalidate my way of finding array length from pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have come across three Questions in techgig Code Gladiator which had method signature like

```
int getMax(int [] a);
```

where "a" is array of positive integers.
which with all the theory I know, I can say is insufficient for solving this with C program.
with observations, though I know they prove wrong in theory, I came up with a method

```
for(i=0;a[i]>=0;i++);
```

which gave correct results in all cases.
Could somebody advise if this can used in all OS and compilers?

Comment: Is it guaranteed to be a zero-terminated array?

Comment: What your code is doing is finding out how many elements there are before a negative number is encountered. If the array is filled with positive numbers, then the first negative number will be at some point past the end of the array and your code will have undefined behavior.

Comment: What is `int [] a` ? I have never seen this syntax in C!

Comment: Sorry for very late reply, but my intent was to say that array is passed as argument and there is no way you can tell its size.

Answer (score 1):

The function has undefined behaviour. Nothing prevents the generated object code by the compiler to scan memory beyond the array.

I tried the following simple program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getMax( int a[] )
{
    int i = 0;
    for ( ; a[i] >= 0; i++ );

    return i;
}

int main( void )
{
    int x = 0;
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int y = 4;

    printf( "&x = %p, a = %p, &y = %p\n", &x, a, &y );
    printf( "%i\n", getMax( a ) );
}
```

And I got the following result

```
&x = 0302FF00, a = 0302FF04, &y = 0302FEFC
55
```

As you can see yourself `55` is not close to the size of the array:).

Running this code on another computer I got result

```
&x = 0xbf8704ac, a = 0xbf8704a0, &y = 0xbf87049c
4
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort!! I was sure it isn't the case that this could be valid

Comment: The OP's function will count non-negative values outside the array (if it doesn't crash first) *and* it will fail to count negative values within the array.

Answer (score 0):

When you read a negative value, it's not part of the array, and so that's potentially "out of bounds".

Also, you don't know how many "not in the array" positive values there were before you hit the negative value.

Consider an array of length 5 `{ 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 }`, then uninitialized data `{7378, 3562, 6271, 73473, -1 }`. Your max is the "bad" value 73473 not the expected 50.

I say you can't do it reliably even on one OS or compiler.